# When exactly does jquery.ajax run the fail callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

I cannot find this in the documentation.
I also did a run through the jquery source and can't find any more info.

By using jquery.ajax, when can I expect the fail callback to be run?

Apart of the following:

- connection problem ( e.g. mobile device lost connection )
- server is down and does not respond

  // EDIT: added after comments, a lot of thanks to @charlietfl :
- http error code equal to or greater then 400
- missing CORS headers

what are the other cases when jquery will run the fail callback?

Comment: parse error , timeout and missing CORS headersare 3 more

Comment: if `dataType` is json for example and response is not valid json == parse error ... or a `jsonp` request that only returns json not jsonp

Comment: oh and don't forget 404 if path is wrong , also authorization failed are 2 more

Comment: and 500 errors at server

Comment: @charlietfl What about other http error codes? Any http error code equal to or greater then 400 what cause fail as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the response status returned is 4xx or 5xx, which indicates a client-side or server-side error respectively. Here's the [entire list](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) of such status codes.